# Gif not loading after form is submitted for certain mobile devices/browsers

Tags: javascript, html, forms

After my HTML form is submitted, it takes a while for all the data to process and for the user to be redirected to the new page where the output will be shown. After the form is submitted, I want to hide it and then display a processing gif until the user is redirected.

My code works for Chrome on the computer. But for mobile browsers, all the code in `displayProcessingGif()` runs except for the first line, which is supposed to make the gif show up. For Safari on the computer, none of the code in `displayProcessingGif()` runs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayProcessingGif(){
        document.getElementById("processingGif").innerHTML='<img src="examplewebsite.com/examplegif.gif">';
        document.getElementById("myForm").style.display="none";
    }
</script>

<form method="POST" id="myForm">
    //different form contents
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" name="submit" onclick="displayProcessingGif();">
</form>

<div id="processingGif">
    <img src="">
</div>
```

Comment: Your string quotes are incorrect. Try `.innerHTML = '<img src="http://examplewebsite.com/examplegif.gif">'`. That being said, you're much better off putting the correct image in your HTML and using JS / CSS to show / hide it

Comment: Tried it and the image shows up on some mobile devices! The gif is not animating/rotating though for mobile Chrome/safari, is this just an issue with the browser itself?

Comment: Maybe the way that the first part of the path is specified.  I've found that sometimes you need to include ./ at the start of the path or / or just nothing.  So have a play with those maybe.

Comment: @Doug Hmm... I'm using a hardcoded link for my gif (https://dda.org.in/OnlinePayslip/Images/pageloader.gif)

Comment: Did you include the https:// bit?  Your example above doesn't include that, but it would be required.

Comment: @Doug Yes I included https://

Answer (score 0):

Changing innerhtml has its own problems. Why don't you rather change image `src`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayProcessingGif(){
        document.getElementById("processingImg").src='examplewebsite.com/examplegif.gif';
        document.getElementById("myForm").style.display="none";
    }
</script>

<div id="processingGif">
    <img src="" id="processingImg">
</div>
```